# Are square brackets required in recursive JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, rest

I have a REST API string created by `XMLHttpRequest().responseText`:

```
{"value":{"patternList":"ERROR,Chase,Theater Chase,Random Colors & Locations,All Colors & Random Locations,Color Wipe,Rainbow,Rainbow Cycle,Theater Chase Rainbow,Larson Scanner,Random,Demo","MQUEUE":"3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10","currentPatternName":"Theater Chase"},"response":"get"}
```

The value of the "value" attribute (confusing, I know) is itself a JSON object. That string is assigned to `result` and `var obj = JSON.parse(result)` fails. However, that same string validates in [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/).

If I insert the square brackets around the embedded JSON object:

```
result = request.responseText;
result = result.replace(":{", ":[{");
result = result.replace("},", "}],");
var obj = JSON.parse(result);
```

All of that works fine. The string with the square brackets also validates on [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/).

Is there a problem with the `JSON.parse()`? I'm debating whether or not I should report the missing square brackets as bug to the API provider.

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: Is the data an array? If so it needs square brackets. If it's a single object, then you just need the curly.

Comment: They aren't called square brackets and curlies, they are called brackets and braces.

Comment: Square brackets are for arrays, curly braces are for objects. Neither of them is required, it depends on what the JSON represents.

Comment: `JSON.parse('{"value":{"patternList":"ERROR,Chase,Theater Chase,Random Colors & Locations,All Colors & Random Locations,Color Wipe,Rainbow,Rainbow Cycle,Theater Chase Rainbow,Larson Scanner,Random,Demo","MQUEUE":"3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10","currentPatternName":"Theater Chase"},"response":"get"}');` works fine in console. You should inspect the response using the browser dev tools or fiddler if you haven't already

Comment: Is it really the `JSON.parse()` that's failing, or something you do with `obj` after you parse it.

Comment: I got the response from firebug, and yes it does work some places, but not  in JSON.parse()

Comment: I didn't write the REST API, but MQUEUE and PatternList should just be strings as far as the API is concerned. I do split them on the comma to make an array, but the API just thinks it's a string.

Comment: Thanks @scrappedcola,  - I was treating value as if it were an array when it was an object.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar,  - I was treating value as if it were an array when it was an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to JSON.parse it again.

```js
var responseText = JSON.stringify({
  "value": {
    "patternList": "ERROR,Chase,Theater Chase,Random Colors & Locations,All Colors & Random Locations,Color Wipe,Rainbow,Rainbow Cycle,Theater Chase Rainbow,Larson Scanner,Random,Demo",
    "MQUEUE": "3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10",
    "currentPatternName": "Theater Chase"
  },
  "response": "get"
});

var responseJSON = JSON.parse(responseText);

var value = responseJSON.value;

var patternList = value.patternList;

alert(patternList);
```

Comment: Thanks Charlie - I was treating value as if it were an array when it was an object.

Comment: Thanks @Charlie Liang Yuan,  - I was treating value as if it were an array when it was an object.